# The term for misspellings that change the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am looking for the term that describes the use of a certain word in a sentence in place of the correct one; a word that happens to look very similar to the one actually needed, but has a different meaning, and that, in turn, causes a big change in the meaning.

A little example: *convolution* and *convulsion.*

I know there is a word for this because I've read about it in Wikipedia, but forgot the term.

EDIT: Thank you all! The term I was looking for was *malapropism.*

Comment: 'A mondegreen /ˈmɒndɨɡriːn/ is a mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as a result of near-homophony, in a way that gives it a new meaning.'{[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)}

Comment: Is this used in the sense of a joke, or accidentally?

Comment: It usually happens accidentally.

Comment: Ironically, I did this yesterday... I thought a cult classic was an occult classic

Comment: Thank you Edwin Ashworth, it was not Mondegreen, but through it I found the term I was looking for. It is called Malapropism.

Comment: This could well be a duplicate of 'What do you call it when someone misunderstands a homonym?'

Comment: Too bad there's no answer to [except](http://grammarist.com/words/accept-vs-except/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are thinking of a **Spoonerism**?

Wikipedia describes this as a slip of the tongue where two letters or syllables get swapped between words. For example "God bless our queer old dean!" is a Spoonerism of "God bless our dear old queen!".

Not sure how reliable the Wikipedia article is. I would have thought a Spoonerism is any case when the wrong word is used to change (as opposed to destroy) the meaning of a sentence. And I'm not sure how widespread that interpretation of the word is.